# Carbon dioxide global warming - marginal rate of warming

Tags: atmospheric-science

Will continuously adding units of carbon dioxide to the atmosphere at a constant rate result in a decreasing rate of warming, a constant rate of warming, or an increasing rate of warming? (Assuming, unrealistically, that ice cover and other factors remain constant.) I've tried to find papers that attempt to answer this question either through data modelling, or small-scale experiments, or both. Assume that we burn the known stock of fossil fuels at a constant rate. I'm interested in this because I want to attempt to calculate the probability of "runaway climate change". (We think this happened on Venus.) It's hard to find research that answers these questions. They seem pretty important.